# How to express lack of preference

Tags: word-choice, politeness

What would be the most natural and polite way to express a lack of preference, for instance, when being asked by a waiter if I prefer a seat at the counter or a separate table?

I've searched Google, Jisho and Midori and come up with:

- 構わないんです（よ）
- 気にしない

but I am very unsure of the level of politeness and I don't want it to sound stilted. In particular, 気にしない seems rude, as jisho.org lists it as "not caring; not giving a damn" and that's not really what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

どちらでもいいですよ, どこでもいいですよ, どちらでも構いません、どっちでも大丈夫です would be natural in this situation. どっちでも気にしません is possible and won't be rude, but a slightly uncommon way of saying it.

Just かまわないです、気にしません is also possible but a slightly odd choice (it would be natural if it was in response to being asked to take a certain seat, instead of being asked what your preference was).

None of the word choices is rude, but perhaps かまわないです、気にしません signals comfortableness being 敬うed. So for example, if you were asked by a 目上の人, better choices are どちらでもいいですよ、どちらでも大丈夫です.